# W10 1903 waking from hibernation with hardware enabled bitlocker results in no file access

Tags: hibernate, bitlocker, windows-10-v1903

1809 woke up out of hibernation in the same situation without any issue. 1903 comes up with a virtually empty explorer starting a neverending search. Clicking can result in some I/O error screen. Start, restart and sleep work fine.

Atm I'm guessing it's a glitch by MS.

Since I can't find any other report on it I would appreciate to hear of any similar experience.

Comment: You might report the issue to MS.

Comment: Thanks. Thought about that and already got tired thinking about the probably tiresome dialogue that would ensue ... In the meantime I put back my 1809 BU and set feature update on the 'semi-annual channel' and postponed by 365 days.